# Счетчик элементов li

Tags: jquery, javascript

Помогите, плиз, с одной штукой. У меня есть список с неким количеством элементов li. Как в каждый элемент вставить цифру, соответствующую номеру списка. Т.е. чтобы после обработки скриптом было так:

```
<ul>
 <li>1</li>
 <li>2</li>
 <li>3</li>
</ul>
```

Я пытался составить цикл, но ничего не вышло(

Заранее спасибо!

---

Вот, что я пытаюсь:

```
$('.count_ul li').each(function() {
    var i = 0;
    i++;
    $(this).wrapInner('<div class="btext"></div>');
    $(this).prepend('<div class="bcount fl">'+ i +'</div>');
});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ошибка в том, что вы инициализируете переменную `i` внутри цикла.
[Пример на jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/p4RPR/)

P.S. в будущем отвечающим будет очень удобно, если вы свой, даже нерабочий, пример поместите в тот же jsfiddle и дадите ссылку.
Удачи :)

Comment: Можно и так http://jsfiddle.net/p4RPR/2/

Answer (score 6):

Сие можно сделать вообще без скриптов, добавляя счётчик стилями.

> `ul {
>     counter-reset: heading; /* Инициируем счетчик */ }
> li:before {
>     counter-increment: heading; /* Указываем идентификатор счетчика */
>     content: counter(heading); /* Выводим номер перед <li> */
>     }`

Немного справки [тут](http://htmlbook.ru/css/counter-increment)

Comment: Там была другая ситуация) Вопрос уже не актуален давно)

Answer (score 5):

сорь, но зачем там вообще i?

```
$('.count_ul li').each(function( index, value ) { 
    console.log(index) // порядковое значение 
})
```

index это уже счетчик, можно им пользоваться

или внутри цикла

```
$('.count_ul li').each(function() { 
    $(this).index() //также дает порядковое значение среди элементов li
})
```

Answer (score 3):

А Зачем?? Почему не использовать конструкцию:

```
<ol>
<li/>
<li/>
</ol>
```

Comment: Я знаю. Там другое кое что. Тут упрощенный пример.

Answer (score 3):

Обязательно jquery? Если нет, то:

```
var ul = document.getElementById( 'count_ul' );
var li = ul.getElementsByTagName( 'li' );
for( var i=0; i < li.length; i++ ) 
{
 /* ... */
}
```

Answer (score 2):

В each первым параметром передается индекс элемента коллекции

```
$('.count_ul li').each(function(i) {
    $(this).wrapInner('<div class="btext"></div>');
    $(this).prepend('<div class="bcount fl">'+ (i + 1) +'</div>');
});
```

// )**.each(function(i)** // i от 0 до $colection.length-1

// fl">'+ **(i + 1)** +'< // без скобок результат будет таким // fl">'+ i + '1' +'<

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.count_ul li').each(function(index) {
    this.innerHTML = '<div class="bcount fl">'+ (index += 1) + '</div>' +
        '<div class="btext"></div>';
});
```